# Laradock: how to enable/install php7 ldap support extension?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ldap, laradock

I have set up docker with laradock.

I'm using the following package

```
"adldap2/adldap2-laravel": "^2.1"
```

I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined function Adldap\ldap_explode_dn()
```

Should I enter my docker workspace and try to install it?

```
docker-compose exec  workspace bash
```

How should I install it?
Seems I can't find php7.0-ldap package from apt-get or apt-cache...

Is it possible to enable it through docker-compose or by editing someway one of docker files? (php-fpm/Dockerfile-70 ?

**EDIT: (DockerFile-70 full contents with Solution provided)**

```
#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Image Setup
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# To edit the 'php-fpm' base Image, visit its repository on Github
#    https://github.com/LaraDock/php-fpm
#
# To change its version, see the available Tags on the Docker Hub:
#    https://hub.docker.com/r/laradock/php-fpm/tags/
#

FROM laradock/php-fpm:7.0--1.2

MAINTAINER Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Mandatory Software's Installation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Mandatory Software's such as ("mcrypt", "pdo_mysql", "libssl-dev", ....)
# are installed on the base image 'laradock/php-fpm' image. If you want
# to add more Software's or remove existing one, you need to edit the
# base image (https://github.com/LaraDock/php-fpm).
#

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Optional Software's Installation
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Optional Software's will only be installed if you set them to `true`
# in the `docker-compose.yml` before the build.
# Example:
#   - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=true
#   - ...
#

#####################################
# xDebug:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_XDEBUG=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_XDEBUG} = true ]; then \
    # Install the xdebug extension
    pecl install xdebug && \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
;fi

# Copy xdebug configration for remote debugging
COPY ./xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

#####################################
# MongoDB:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_MONGO=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MONGO} = true ]; then \
    # Install the mongodb extension
    pecl install mongodb && \
    docker-php-ext-enable mongodb \
;fi

#####################################
# ZipArchive:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE} = true ]; then \
    # Install the zip extension
    pecl install zip && \
    docker-php-ext-enable zip \
;fi

#####################################
# PHP Memcached:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_MEMCACHED=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MEMCACHED} = true ]; then \
    # Install the php memcached extension
    curl -L -o /tmp/memcached.tar.gz "https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/archive/php7.tar.gz" \
    && mkdir -p memcached \
    && tar -C memcached -zxvf /tmp/memcached.tar.gz --strip 1 \
    && ( \
        cd memcached \
        && phpize \
        && ./configure \
        && make -j$(nproc) \
        && make install \
    ) \
    && rm -r memcached \
    && rm /tmp/memcached.tar.gz \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
;fi

#####################################
# PHP Aerospike:
#####################################

ARG INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION=false
ENV INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION ${INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION}
# Copy aerospike configration for remote debugging
COPY ./aerospike.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/aerospike.ini
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION} = true ]; then \
    # Install the php aerospike extension
curl -L -o /tmp/aerospike-client-php.tar.gz "https://github.com/luciano-jr/aerospike-client-php/archive/    master.tar.gz" \
    && mkdir -p aerospike-client-php \
    && tar -C aerospike-client-php -zxvf /tmp/aerospike-client-php.tar.gz --strip 1 \
    && ( \
        cd aerospike-client-php/src/aerospike \
        && phpize \
        && ./build.sh \
        && make install \
    ) \
    && rm /tmp/aerospike-client-php.tar.gz \
;fi

#####################################
# Opcache:
#####################################
ARG INSTALL_OPCACHE=false
RUN if [ ${INSTALL_OPCACHE} = true ]; then \
    docker-php-ext-install opcache && \
    docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
;fi

# Copy opcache configration
COPY ./opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini

#####################################
# LDAP:
#####################################
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install libldap2-dev -y && \
    #rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install ldap



#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Final Touch
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#

ADD ./laravel.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
ADD ./laravel.pool.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/

RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

WORKDIR /var/www/laravel

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check this out:

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/75

Basically you need this in your php-fpm docker file:

```
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install libldap2-dev -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && \
    docker-php-ext-install ldap
```

Comment: I updated the php-fpm/Dockerfile-70 with the snippent. It seems rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \ causes an error. That doesn't let me build php-fpm after edit:: rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/*': No such file or directory

Comment: @koalaok You can safely remove that line, as it is just a cleanup tasks to keep the size down. Not too sure why it wouldn't work though. What does your full Dockerfile look like?

Comment: It' s the common Dockerfile-70 in laradock git repo latest. Anyway I noticed that line is already present some rows below. "Final touch" . I'll paste Dockerfile 70 in my question as a edit - formatted